# Flutter: Dynamically Updating Icon in AppBar Based on ChangeNotifier State

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm developing a Flutter app where I have a ChangeNotifier service that manages file upload processes. This service has a boolean isUploading property that tracks whether files are currently being uploaded. I'm trying to reflect the upload state in the UI by changing an icon in the AppBar of a FileViewPage widget based on isUploading.

My app structure includes a MultiProvider at the top level in the main function:

```
void main() { // Main function is the base of the app I need the icon change in the next page not here.
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SharedFilesProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CloudService()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(), // MyApp is the root widget of your application
    ),
  );
}
```

On the next page (which is a few navigation steps into the app), I'm trying to use the state of isUploading to toggle between two icons in the AppBar:

```
final isUpdating = context.watch<CloudService>().isUploading ?? false;

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          isUpdating ? Icons.cloud_upload_outlined : Icons.cloud_queue_outlined,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () => {},
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

In CloudService, the isUploading state changes within a pushChanges method, which performs asynchronous file uploads and updates isUploading accordingly:

```
class CloudService extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool? _isUploading;

  bool? get isUploading => _isUploading;

  // Method to push changes, updates _isUploading and calls notifyListeners()
  Future<void> pushChanges() async {
    _isUploading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    // Simulated file upload process
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    _isUploading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The icon does not update dynamically when isUploading changes. I expect the icon to switch to Icons.cloud_upload_outlined when isUploading is true and back to Icons.cloud_queue_outlined when false, but the icon remains static once the page is loaded.

I performed a hot restart to ensure it's not a hot reload issue, and I've confirmed through debugging that notifyListeners() is being called as expected when isUploading changes.

I think I couldn't connect provider with appBar.
It is not changing false to true while uploading.

Comment: Where are you calling the `pushChanges` in your code?

Comment: @pcba-dev I call pushChanges from the same view as the appbar button, at initstate.

Comment: Could you provide a simplified version of your full code? It is not clear how in initState you are calling that `pushChanges` (which it is not recommended since it has side effects). I have tested calling `pushChanges` using the `onPressed` callback of the `IconButton` and it works as expected

Comment: So basically I have a database that keeps track of user's changes on the files. If there are items changed or uploaded into app I mark their sync value as false. As the app runs in the second page I start the checking mechanism like this :   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkCloudSyncMethodAndSync();} and this function is simply initializes the CloudService class. Inside of initialize, there are silentLogin and pushChanges method. I already shared the pushChanges method. I wonder if this Provider thing works with user input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initState` is a method which is called when a stateful widget is inserted into the widgets tree. It is useful for performing initialization tasks that depend on the widget's *BuildContext*, as well as for any tasks that need to be performed once the widget is fully initialized and ready for interaction. Think of it as a way on performing tasks that cannot be done in the constructor of your class because they rely need to have access to the context. `initState is called after the constructor of the State class, so any data initialized in the constructor will already be available.

While it's possible to make initial network calls in the `initState` method, it's generally not recommended to do it since it will imply that every time such widget is inserted in the tree that call will be performed.

There is not an easy solution to your question. It seems you have a problem which involves the **state-management of your app**. I would recommend moving that network call to somewhere else which does not depend on your widgets tree but rather of the apps global state (maybe to your "main()" function). Since you are performing asynchronous calls and interacting with a network service, you cannot rely on *simple app state management* techniques. I would recommend to:

1. Understand the [difference between ephemeral state and app state](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app)
2. [Learning about the different approaches](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) for complex apps state-management.

There is no correct choice for which state-management approach to use, but since you have already started Providers and ChangeNotifier, I would recommend upgrading to [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/docs/introduction/why_riverpod).

Comment: Hey, I moved the method call for pushChanges into Main() as you mentioned and now it works like clockwork. I worked this for 3-4 days and I don't feel satisfied yet I solved it thanks to you. I have much to learn that is for sure but idk how I am going to understand all of that as a non CS programmer.

Comment: Glad it helped, you can upvote the answer if you found it helpful. The key concept here for Flutter is that you should almost never have "business logic" (triggering tasks, fetching/posting data, workflows, ...) in you `build()` and `initState()` since these methods are invoked for "rendering" and placing your widgets in the UI

Comment: It says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." When I have the number I will. Thank you buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar kind of issue while I was working on a shopping app, I want to update cart count in app bar on click of add to cart in product screen and it should update on previous and next screen both. So I have made some change in my code and logic.

1. I make a small widget which is consumer of listener and only show the cart count.
2. move all the networks/async code to different class and after that trigger the notifier method.

You can try the same logic in you code, create a small widget which hold this icon button that you want to change when notify listener execute. this widget should be consumer of your notifier.

segregate you notifer and async code and call notifer method to update updating flag when you upload process is completed.

I have created a simplified version of my logic, you can reference it.
https://github.com/pkumarprojects/notifier_update

"I apologies for any mistakes in my English."

Answer (score -1):

Well after many trials I found out that I am actually getting the data back from CloudService class. When I call the class's method like this from initState:

```
final isUpdating = Provider.of<GoogleCloudService>(context,listen: false);
isUpdating.initialize();
```

The way I found it was an unrelated button click, that button click has nothing to do with this sequence of functions but, opens a sub menu in the view and closes it with a **setState**.

When setState works the iconButton does the necessary update on its icon value. Problem now is how to make setState work when this function is working... @pcba-dev

Comment: You should add this information as a comment or to the initial question instead of as an answer, and the delete the answer.