# Convert Future<Object> to Object model after parse json in initState flutter

Tags: json, flutter, asynchronous, future, flutter-futurebuilder

Im new in flutter so Iam playing aroung and would be nice some hints, Illl apreciate alot. Thank you for your timeind advance.
I parse data from http, so I use Future but i want to convert into real object

**Data Model**

```
class ApiService {
  Future<Survey> getSurvey() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(ApiConstants.baseUrl));
import 'dart:convert';

class Survey {
  String id;
  String title;
  String description;
  String startedAt;
  String endedAt;
  String imageUrl;
  String termsAndConditionsUrl;
  String finishText;
  List<Question> questions;

  
  factory Survey.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Survey(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"],
        startedAt: json["startedAt"],
        endedAt: json["endedAt"],
        imageUrl: json["imageUrl"],
        termsAndConditionsUrl: json["termsAndConditionsUrl"],
        finishText: json["finishText"],
        questions: List<Question>.from(
            json["questions"].map((x) => Question.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "startedAt": startedAt,
        "endedAt": endedAt,
        "imageUrl": imageUrl,
        "termsAndConditionsUrl": termsAndConditionsUrl,
        "finishText": finishText,
        "questions": List<dynamic>.from(questions.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}
```

**Data call I guess here is where I can do what I want**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:healy_app/models/constants.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/models/survey_model.dart';

class ApiService {
  Future<Survey> getSurvey() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(ApiConstants.baseUrl));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Survey.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
```

**Page with widget where i would like to have the objet not the Future<>**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/models/survey_model.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/widgets/front_accept_buttom.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/widgets/front_terms_checkbox.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/widgets/front_title.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/widgets/start_image.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({super.key, required this.survey});
  late Future<Survey> survey;

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final String appBarText = "SURVEY";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(appBarText),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<Survey>(
              future: widget.survey,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      StartImage(url: snapshot.data!.imageUrl),
                      FrontTitle(
                        titleText: snapshot.data!.title,
                        descriptionText: snapshot.data!.description,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          FutureBuilder<Survey>(
              future: widget.survey,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return FrontTermsCheckbox(checkboxText: snapshot.data!.title);
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          FrontAcceptButtom(
            onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/survey'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/models/api_service.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/models/survey_model.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/screens/home_page.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/screens/survey_questions.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  late Future<Survey> survey;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    survey = ApiService().getSurvey();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => HomePage(
              survey: survey,
            ),
        '/survey': (context) => QuizQuestions(
              survey: survey,
            ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to load async data on InitState method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901002/is-there-a-way-to-load-async-data-on-initstate-method)

Comment: Although this works for this very simple app, I would recommend NOT performing this type of actions in `initState`. This function is invoked when a widget is inserted in the widgets tree, which can happen several times in an app (for example when a user navigates to a route with that widget several times). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77968398/21188902) to a similar question.